# How to get multiple value in Array from linqQuery from foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-query-syntax

Hi I want to get result of my query in Array which is executed in foreach loop,i have my custom class but whenever I try to save it in variable it shows error :

it is not possible to convert genriccustom class to my custom class

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

                    var result = entities.USERS.SingleOrDefault(x => x.USER_NAME.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));


                    var Result = (from p in entities.Apps where p.USERID == result.USERID select p).ToList();

                    var children = new List<InsuredSummary>();

                    foreach (var queryresult in Result)
                    {
                        var query_result = (from b in entities.USERS
                                                // join c in entities.APP_INFORMATION on Result.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID equals c.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID
                                                // join d in entities.APP_INFO_VEHICLE on Result.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID equals d.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID
                                                //  join e in entities.APP_INFO_VEHICLE_OPTIONS_ACCESSORIES on Result.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID equals e.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID
                                            join f in entities.Apps.Where(y => y.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID == queryresult.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID) on b.USERID equals f.USERID
                                            select new
                                            //USER
                                            // InsuredSummary
                                            {
                                                USERID = b.USERID,
                                                //INSURED_APPLICATION_ID = queryresult.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID,
                                                //User
                                                USER_NAME = b.USER_NAME,
                                                INSURED_FIRST_NAME = b.INSURED_FIRST_NAME,
                                                INSURED_LAST_NAME = b.INSURED_LAST_NAME,
                                                INSURED_EMAIL = b.INSURED_EMAIL,

                                                //App_Information


                                            }).ToList();

                       // Want to save  query_result in Array[]

                    }

                    return query_result;


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because in your foreach loop, every time you're creating an anonymous type in your query and you can't aggregate all of them in one array.
For doing this it's better to first get all insuredApplicationIDs and after that in one query get all users that have that id in their Apps.

```
var insuredApplicationIDs = Result.Select(r => r.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID);
var queryResaut = (from b in entities.USERS
                   join f in entities.Apps.Where(y => insuredApplicationIDs.Contains(y.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID)) on b.USERID equals f.USERID
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            USERID = b.USERID,
                                            //INSURED_APPLICATION_ID = queryresult.INSURED_APPLICATION_ID,
                                            //User
                                            USER_NAME = b.USER_NAME,
                                            INSURED_FIRST_NAME = b.INSURED_FIRST_NAME,
                                            INSURED_LAST_NAME = b.INSURED_LAST_NAME,
                                            INSURED_EMAIL = b.INSURED_EMAIL,

                                            //App_Information
                                        }).ToArray()
```

Comment: I need this value also INSURED_APPLICATION_ID